# Horizontally align several items in multiple rows

Tags: css

I need to align several elements inside an external div.

The code of the elements is like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  :
  :
  <div>ItemN</div>
</div>
```

The width of each item is the same.

I know that there will be 5 items per row, but I don't know how many items there will be in total.

What I need is that the remaining items will be centered inside the last row.

For example, for 7 items:

```
[xxx][xxx][xxx][xxx][xxx]
        [xxx][xxx]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add `dispaly:flex`, `flex-wrap:wrap;` and `justify-content:center;` to `.box` and set for every div inside `width:20%;`

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.box > div {
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
  <div>ItemN</div>
</div>
```